# MAC address conversion into byte array in python

Tags: python, networking, python-3.x, python-2.7, arrays

I have a mac address in this format

```
00:45:36:45:f2:00
```

I want to convert this mac address into byte array. I mean, by removing the ':' in between, I get total of 6 bytes and those 6 bytes should sit as six bytes in a byte array. And how is that byte array converted into an integer? Is there any in-built function in python that would do that with very very less execution time(like in microseconds)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2.7,

```
macstr = addr.replace(':', '').decode('hex')
```

In Python 3,

```
import binascii
macbytes = binascii.unhexlify(addr.replace(b':', b''))
```

Comment: if i do in this way, total of 12 bytes are in byte array, not 6. in the mac address, f2 has to sit as 1 byte, not as 2 bytes in the byte array

Answer (score 1):

In python version 3.10.1

code is

```
import binascii
macbytes = binascii.unhexlify(addr.replace(':', ''))
```

the replace function/definition should be provided with strings-' ' and not bytes-b' '